# Generating new column containing modal value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, mode

I have the following data frame:

```
skus = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2]
prices = [10.99, 10.99, 11.50, 9.99, 9.99]
data = dict(skus=skus, prices=prices)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=data.keys())
```

How do I create another column `prices_mode` that looks like this:

```
   skus  prices  prices_modal
0     1   10.99         10.99
1     1   10.99         10.99
2     1   11.50         10.99
3     2    9.99          9.99
4     2    9.99          9.99
```

i.e. it's the mode of the prices for each unique `sku` value.

Comment: what is a 'modal price'? lowest price?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Method 1

Using `groupby`, `transform` and `pd.Series.mode`:

```
df['prices_modal'] = df.groupby('skus')['prices'].transform(lambda x: pd.Series.mode(x)[0])

   skus  prices  prices_modal
0     1   10.99         10.99
1     1   10.99         10.99
2     1   11.50         10.99
3     2    9.99          9.99
4     2    9.99          9.99
```

---

#### Method 2

Using `statistics.mode`

```
from statistics import mode

df['prices_modal'] = df.groupby('skus')['prices'].transform(mode)

   skus  prices  prices_modal
0     1   10.99         10.99
1     1   10.99         10.99
2     1   11.50         10.99
3     2    9.99          9.99
4     2    9.99          9.99
```

Comment: That's amazing. Thank you very much